# Line of action for special cases of an answer supposed to be a comment

Tags: discussion

This answer got me thinking :
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/191025/57075

It's actually supposed to be a comment on some other guy's answer, but the guy doesn't have enough rep to comment. Maybe it's a valuable critique to the other guy's answer. Should I flag such answers or not ?

Comment: To make the options clear, a moderator can convert an answer into a comment on either the question or another answer associated with the same question. For myself I don't like to encourage such non-answers unless the comment is very insightful, however.

Comment: It's good that you asked this question, but for some reason it bothers me a bit that the question even needed to be asked. Maybe it's that there should be no special cases, no exceptions, no ambiguity, etc. to the rule that only answers should be posted as answers (except to the extent that we can debate whether something is an answer or not), and it bothers me if that's not clear.

Comment: [The converse question](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/964/44126): answers posted as comments.

Comment: @DavidZ I think the greater intention of my question was whether such answers should be 'deleted' as such, since I was under the impression that mods delete such answers invariably once I flag them. It was supposed to be discussion for whether mods should delete such answers or not. Now that it has been clarified that they can convert an answer into a comment if it is valuable enough, I'm left with no doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments are comments, not answers.  Flag them.

Comment: That's what I normally do. Since you have read through the question and seen many such cases, can you elaborate as to why it is immaterial that we may be losing an important opinion ?

Comment: @Gaurav: Often times, answers that are really comments are turned into comments by moderators, not outright deleted.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, I feel this is indeed an answer. Not particularly complete, but an answer nonetheless. In general, though, if it looks like a comment, flag it as such. If the comment is still valuable then a mod can convert it to a comment.